# Using showAndWait in JavaFX application

Tags: java, javafx

I'm creating a Login which uses Single Sign On. To do this, if the company a user logs in with is SSO enabled, then a JavaFX `WebView` will open, allowing the user to login. This login will be entirely web based so no real data capture on my part is required.

I have two classes, `LoginManager` and `SSO`. `LoginManager` checks to see if the company is SSOEnabled, and then goes to `SSO` if it is. From here, I create the UI, and then using `Platform.runLater()`, go to the method which opens the `webview`. However, my program goes to `initJFXPanel` and then instantly goes back to `LoginManager` to execute code there, which causes issues.

What I would like is to be able to go through all of `SSO` until it reaches a certain webpage and then I use frame.dispose(), then go back to `LoginManager` to continue. I think I need to use a `Stage` and `showAndWait()` but I'm not really sure how to go about this.

I tried creating a Stage inside `initJFXPanel` but this didn't work as it goes back to `LoginManager` before it has the chance to do anything, and I also tried setting the stage in `createPopup` but I wasn't sure what to use as the stage or the scene.

Here is my code:

LoginManager class

```
public class LoginManager {

    private boolean bSSOEnabled = true;

    private void Login() {

        // get company details

        if(bSSOEnabled) {
            new SSO();
        }

        // once SSO is done, continue with execution
    }
}
```

SSO class

```
public class SSO {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JFXPanel fxPanel;
    private JPanel containerPanel;
    final static String WEBVIEW = "WebView";

    public SSO(){
        createPopup();
    }

    private void createPopup(){

        Dimension size = new Dimension(480, 80);

        frame = new JFrame("Web Login");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        containerPanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());

        fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        fxPanel.setSize(size);

        Platform.runLater(() -> initJFXPanel(frame, fxPanel));

        containerPanel.add(fxPanel, WEBVIEW);

        frame.add(containerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setPreferredSize(size);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    private void initJFXPanel(final JFrame frame, final JFXPanel fxPanel){

        Group group = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(group);
        fxPanel.setScene(scene);

        WebView webview = new WebView();

        group.getChildren().add(webview);
        webview.setMinSize(500, 640);
        webview.setMaxSize(500, 640);

        CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
        java.net.CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);

        webview.getEngine().load("http://google.com/");


        if(webview.getEngine().getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("cookie url")) {
            // harvest the cookies
        }
        else if(webview.getEngine().getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("end url")) {
            frame.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated. I've been stuck on this for a whole day and am not sure what to do at all.

Comment: 1. Do you need to mix Swing and JavaFX? It would be easier if you could use just one toolkit. You definitely do not want to use both `JFrame` and `Stage` in the same application, so if you are committed to using Swing, then embedding the `WebView` in a `JFXPanel` and displaying it in a `JFrame` is the correct approach. 2. What thread is the `login()` method in `LoginManager` invoked from?

Comment: @James_D 1. no I don't need to use anything in particular - I didn't write the UI, somebody else did, abandoned the project and then I got lumped with it, so I don't mind changing it if it's necessary to implement showAndWait if that's the best way 2. I think it's in the main one?

Comment: Is the rest of the UI that is already written in Swing or in JavaFX?

Comment: @James_D the rest of it is all in swing

Comment: In that case you should use a swing window for this part, with a JFXPanel to display the web view. The equivalent to `showAndWait` for a swing window is to use a JDialog and set its modality type, eg to APPLICATION_MODAL. Then when you make it visible it will block execution until it is dismissed, which you can do just by calling `setVisible(false)`. You need a bit of threading trickery as you have three threads (main thread, AWT thread, and FX thread). I can post a full solution later when I am back at a computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application is a Swing application, and you need to use a `WebView`, then the correct approach is the one you have shown in your code, i.e. use a Swing window and embed the `WebView` in a `JFXPanel`. It is usually a bad idea to mix windows from the two frameworks, so I would recommend avoiding using a `Stage` at all.

The way to make code in Swing block until the user dismisses a window, i.e. the Swing equivalent of a JavaFX `Stage.showAndWait()` call, is to use a `JDialog` and make it modal. As well as blocking input to any other window, this will block execution (of the AWT Event Dispatch thread) until the dialog is dismissed.

What makes this a little trickier is that you have three threads to work with: the AWT Event Dispatch Thread, the JavaFX Application Thread, and the main thread. Showing the modal dialog will block the AWT Event Dispatch thread, but you want (if I understand the question correctly) the main thread to be blocked. Additionally, you must only create, modify, and show your Swing components on the AWT Event Dispatch thread, and you must only create, modify, and show your JavaFX nodes on the JavaFX Application Thread.

So I think you want something like this:

```
public class SSO {

    private JDialog dialog;
    private JFXPanel fxPanel;
    private JPanel containerPanel;
    final static String WEBVIEW = "WebView";

    public SSO(){
        // creates Swing components: MUST be called on AWT Event thread
        createPopup();
    }

    private void createPopup(){

        Dimension size = new Dimension(480, 80);

        dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.setTite("Web Login");

        // make dialog modal:
        dialog.setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);

        // oops: don't want this:
        // dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // but this:
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        containerPanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());

        fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        fxPanel.setSize(size);

        Platform.runLater(() -> initJFXPanel(dialog, fxPanel));

        containerPanel.add(fxPanel, WEBVIEW);

        dialog.add(containerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        dialog.setPreferredSize(size);
        dialog.setResizable(false);
        dialog.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);

        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        dialog.setVisible(true);

    }

    private void initJFXPanel(final JDialog dialog, final JFXPanel fxPanel){

        Group group = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(group);
        fxPanel.setScene(scene);

        WebView webview = new WebView();

        group.getChildren().add(webview);
        webview.setMinSize(500, 640);
        webview.setMaxSize(500, 640);

        CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
        java.net.CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);

        webview.getEngine().load("http://google.com/");


        if(webview.getEngine().getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("cookie url")) {
            // harvest the cookies
        }
        else if(webview.getEngine().getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("end url")) {
            // this will hide the dialog and release the event dispatch thread
            // that is waiting for it, but it must be called on the event dispatch thread
            // not sure of your exact requirements, but you may need to do this
            // in the if clause as well?
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> dialog.setVisible(false));
        }

    }

}
```

Now if you instantiate `SSO`, the code will block until the dialog is dismissed. However, you must do that on the AWT Event Dispatch thread. The trick to waiting for that to complete on the main thread is to represent the call to `new SSO()` as a [`FutureTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html), submit the `FutureTask` to `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`, and then, back on the main thread, call `get()` on the `FutureTask`: this will block until the task completes. You need to be careful here: if you inadvertently do this on the Event Dispatch Thread, you end up in deadlock, as the event dispatch thread will block, waiting for something to happen on the event dispatch thread... So you probably want a guard against that to be safe.

So your code probably needs to look like this:

```
public class LoginManager {

    private boolean bSSOEnabled = true;

    private void Login() {

        // get company details

        if(bSSOEnabled) {
            if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
                // already on EDT, just invoke the SSO which will block 
                // until the dialog is dismissed:
                new SSO();
            } else {
                // create FutureTask to show dialog, etc:
                FutureTask<Void> ssoTask = new FutureTask<>(SSO:new, null);
                // submit task to AWT event dispatch thread:
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(ssoTask);
                // wait for task to complete, i.e. for dialog to be dismissed:
                try {
                    ssoTask.get();
                } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
                    // thread was interrupted, representing cancelation of some kind:
                    System.out.println("Thread interrupted");
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                } catch (ExecutionException ee) {
                    // something went wrong...
                    throw new RuntimeException(ee);
                }
            }
        }



    // once SSO is done, continue with execution
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great, thank you so much! Swapping frame for a dialog seems to work without any threading code in LoginManager - will this impact my program negatively?