# Wait for function to return until JFrame closed in JavaFX thread

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling, jdialog

The function below puts a Java FX panel in a Swing JDialog, adds a webview to the JFX Panel, and renders an HTML report in it.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to make the displayHTMLOutput function to return only when the HTML has been displayed and the JDialog has been closed. As the content is rendered in the JavaFX thread I have been unable to catch the closing dialog. How can this be accomplished?

```
/* Displays a given OutputTable object in a dialog */
public static void displayHTMLOutput(OutputTable table) {

    /* Create modal dialog and JFXPanel */
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog((Window) null);
    JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();

    /* Add JFXPanel to dialog */
    dialog.add(jfxPanel);

    /* Configure the dialog */

    dialog.setSize(1200, 800);
    dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    /* Maps escape key to closing the dialog */
    key(dialog);

    /* sets an icon for the dialog */
    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("icons/report.png");
    dialog.setIconImage(img.getImage());

    /* Show the dialog */
    dialog.setVisible(true);

    /* Runs ons the JavaFX Application Thread at a later time */
    Platform.runLater(() -> {

        /* Create webview and bind to scene */
        WebView webView = new WebView();        
        jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(webView));

        /* Load the html in a webview */
        webView.getEngine().loadContent(DisplayHtml.getOutputHTMLOutputTable("template.html", table));      

        /* Do some actions on the dialog */
        dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        dialog.setModal(true);
        dialog.requestFocus();

    });

}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39441199/using-showandwait-in-javafx-application). If I understand the answer (and your question) correctly, the way you make execution stop until the `JDialog` has been closed is to make it modal.

Comment: Thanks @Slaw, the post you referenced enabled me to change my code to get it working!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Slaw 's referenced post, I was able to rewrite my code to get the desired result. Turns out the window should be made visible only AFTER the webview code has been been placed on the Java FX Thread.

```
/* Displays a given OutputTable object in a dialog */
public static void displayHTMLOutput(OutputTable table) {

    /* Create modal dialog and JFXPanel */
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog((Window) null);
    JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();

    /* Add JFXPanel to dialog */
    dialog.add(jfxPanel);

    /* Configure the dialog */

    dialog.setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    dialog.setSize(1200, 800);

    /* Maps escape key to closing the dialog */
    key(dialog);

    /* sets an icon for the dialog */
    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("icons/report.png");
    dialog.setIconImage(img.getImage());

    /* Runs ons the JavaFX Application Thread at a later time */
    Platform.runLater(() -> {

        /* Create webview and bind to scene */
        WebView webView = new WebView();        
        jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(webView));

        /* Load the html in a webview */
        webView.getEngine().loadContent(DisplayHtml.getOutputHTMLOutputTable("template.html", table));      

    });

    /* Do some actions on the dialog */
    dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    dialog.requestFocus();
    dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    dialog.setVisible(true);

    /* Test is now only printed to console when the dialog is closed */
    System.out.println("test");     
}
```